# Python users creation script

Tags: python

For training reasons im trying to write a python script that creates and sets user accounts and passwords :

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen

users = ["user1"]
default_passwd = 'password'

for user in users:
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(["useradd" ,user])
    proc = Popen(['echo' ,default_passwd ,  '|' , 'passwd', user, '--stdin'])
    proc.communicate()
```

While the user is created , the passwd process fails.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use shell pipes with subprocess. Instead, try and use `subprocess.PIPE` for communication between processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Naren answer is neat and much more readable; but for the purpose of answering your `subprocess` question, it should be like this

```
import subprocess

users = ["user1"]
default_passwd = 'password'

for user in users:
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['useradd', user, '-p'])
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', default_passwd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p1.communicate(proc.stdout)
    proc.communicate()
```

- p1 opens a subshell with `useradd user1` command executed and waits for input
- proc then executes `echo default_passwd`, but instead of sending output to sys.stdout, it pipes it to subprocess.PIPE
- The communicate on p1 sends the output of `proc.stdout` to the `stdin` of p1 and waits for it completion
- The last commands wait for `proc` process to finish and exit

Comment: Thanks Vinny for your comment. It works but it seems that does not set the password correct.

Comment: I missed the `-p` param; try it now

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you pass password along with command `useradd`?
so that it creates a user with password without prompting!!

```
import os
import crypt

password ="your-password" 
crypted_password = crypt.crypt(password,"22")
os.system("useradd -p "+ crypted_password +" student")
```

Comment: Nice example where `os.system` is much simpler than subprocess module